# How to add axis label (x and y) and rotate y axis numbers with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to add axis label (x and y) and rotate y axis numbers with Matplotlib like on the image below ?

[image]

I tried `plt.yticks(rotation=45)` to rotate the y axis numbers but it's not taken into account.

Besides, I'm also trying to have one 0 instead of two in my example code and a square grid instead of rectangles.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    # adds arrows at the ends of each axis
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style('->')
    # adds X and Y-axis from the origin
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

ax.axis['yzero'].set_ticklabel_direction("-")

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    # hides borders
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
ax.plot(x, -x**2+16, color="#ab74a6", linewidth=3)

plt.title(r'$y = -x^2+16$')

plt.yticks(rotation=45)

plt.axis([-5, 5, -10, 20])

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm confused. The numbers in you example image aren't rotated

Comment: @PaulH if I don't use `add_subplot`, the rotation works, but I don't get something like on my example image anymore with x an y axis only with arrows.

Comment: Does [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/recipes/centered_spines_with_arrows.html) example help?

Comment: @gherka Yes, a lot, it fixes most of my issues and simplifies the code! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code example using `spines` rather than `SubplotZero`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
ax.plot(x, -x**2+16, color="#ab74a6", linewidth=3)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# hide one of the zero labels and adjust the other
ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[3].label1.set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[3].label1.set_horizontalalignment("right")

ax.plot(1, 0, ">k", transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)
ax.plot(0, 1, "^k", transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False)

ax.axis('equal')
ax.set_xlabel('x', position=(1,0), ha='right')
ax.set_ylabel('y', position=(0,1), ha='right', rotation=0)

plt.title(r'$y = -x^2+16$', y=1.08)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to add `x` and `y` labels, get nice square grid and arrows ?

Comment: Sure. See updated answer. Because the aspect of the figure (10, 5) isn't square, the grid isn't square either, but you can easily change that. Square pictures just don't look as good on SO :)